# arcgis to_featurelayer() crashes kernel with ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"

Tags: installation, arcgis-python-api, importerror, hosted-feature-layer, spatially-enabled-dataframe

My python kernel and ArcGIS both crash when I try to export a spatially enabled DataFrame to a featurelayer or featureclass in one of my virtual environments.

In addition to the python and ArcGIS crash messages, I also get the error:

> ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"

While I've seen some [posts on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14474) about that error message, I haven't seen anything that helps with the SEDF export.

However, trying the same code in a different virtual environment *does* work, so it seems to be something to do with my conda environment.

Here's a reprex:

```
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(url = url, username = username, password = password)
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1], 
                   'longitude' : 143.01363,
                   'latitude' : 44.77826})

sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_xy(
    df=df,
    x_column='longitude',
    y_column='latitude',
    sr=4326
)
sdf.spatial.to_featurelayer('test', gis = gis)
```

Here is the result of `conda list` in the environment where the code fails:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     2.2.0            py37haa95532_2
appdirs                   1.4.4                      py_0
arcgis                    1.9.0                 py37_2172    esri
arcgispro                 2.8                           0    esri
arcpy                     2.8             py37_arcgispro_29734  [arcgispro]  esri
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py37h2bbff1b_1
arrow-cpp                 1.0.1                         3    esri
asn1crypto                1.4.0                      py_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
aws-c-common              0.4.57               ha925a31_1
aws-c-event-stream        0.1.6                hd77b12b_5
aws-checksums             0.1.9                ha925a31_0
aws-sdk-cpp               1.8.185              hd77b12b_0
azure-core                1.12.0                     py_0    esri
azure-storage-blob        12.8.0                     py_0    esri
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
black                     19.10b0                    py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blinker                   1.4              py37haa95532_0
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37h2a96729_1
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h2bbff1b_1003
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2021.7.5             haa95532_1
cached-property           1.5.2                      py_0
certifi                   2021.5.30        py37haa95532_0
cffi                      1.14.6           py37h2bbff1b_0
cfitsio                   3.470                he774522_6
cftime                    1.0.0b1                  py37_0    esri
chardet                   4.0.0           py37haa95532_1003
click                     7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0
cligj                     0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cppzmq                    4.4.1                         2    esri
cryptography              3.4.7            py37h71e12ea_0
curl                      7.78.0               h86230a5_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
despatch                  0.1.0                    py37_0    esri
docutils                  0.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0            py37haa95532_0
expat                     2.4.1                h6c2663c_2
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
fiona                     1.8.4           py37h0d92105_1001    conda-forge
flake8                    3.9.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.10.1                   vc14_0  [vc14]  esri
freexl                    1.0.6                h2bbff1b_0
frictionless              4.16.2             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0    esri
gdal                      2.3.3           arcgispro_py37_16747  [arcgispro]  esri
geographiclib             1.52                     pypi_0    pypi
geopandas                 0.9.0                      py_1
geopandas-base            0.9.0                      py_1
geopy                     2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
geos                      3.8.0                h33f27b4_0
h5py                      2.10.0          py37_arcgispro_10  [arcgispro]  esri
hdf4                      4.2.13               h712560f_2
hdf5                      1.10.6               h7ebc959_0
html5lib                  1.1                        py_0
hypothesis                6.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.5            arcgispro_0  [arcgispro]  esri
idna                      2.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        3.10.0               hd3eb1b0_0
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2020.0            arcgispro_166  [arcgispro]  esri
ipykernel                 5.1.1                    py37_0    esri
ipython                   7.21.0                   py37_0    esri
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py37_0
isodate                   0.6.0                      py_0    esri
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.18.0                   py37_0    esri
jinja2                    3.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9d                            0    esri
json5                     0.9.4                    py37_0    esri
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0    esri
jupyter_console           6.2.0                      py_2    esri
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                    py37_3    esri
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.5.1                   py37_10    esri
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_2    esri
jupyter_highlight_selected_word 0.2.0                    py37_2    esri
jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.4                    py37_1    esri
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.4.1                    py37_1    esri
jupyter_server            1.5.1                    py37_0    esri
jupyterlab                3.1.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_server         2.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
kealib                    1.4.14               hde4a422_0
keyring                   21.4.0                   py37_0    esri
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py37hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.19.2               h5b6d351_0
lerc                      3.0                pyh39e3cac_0    esri
libcurl                   7.78.0               h86230a5_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                hf59b723_4
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libpq                     12.2                 hb652d5d_1
libsodium                 1.0.18                        1    esri
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
libxml2                   2.9.10              arcgispro_0  [arcgispro]  esri
libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0
lxml                      4.6.3            py37h9b66d53_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
m2w64-expat               2.1.1                         2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gettext             0.19.7                        2
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-xz                  5.2.2                         2
mapclassify               2.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
markupsafe                2.0.1            py37h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.3.1           py37_arcgispro_0  [arcgispro]  esri
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h64f37c6_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1001
mkl                       2020.0            arcgispro_167  [arcgispro]  esri
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37h196d8e1_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py37h46781fe_0
mkl_random                1.2.0                    py37_0    esri
mpmath                    1.2.1            py37haa95532_0
msrest                    0.6.21                     py_0    esri
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0
mypy_extensions           0.4.3                    py37_0
nbclassic                 0.2.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0    esri
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_1    esri
netcdf4                   1.5.4           py37_arcgispro_6  [arcgispro]  esri
networkx                  2.5                      py37_0    esri
nlohmann_json             3.7.0                         1    esri
nose                      1.3.7           pyhd3eb1b0_1006
notebook                  5.7.10                   py37_0
ntlm-auth                 1.4.0                      py_0    esri
numexpr                   2.7.3            py37hcbcaa1e_0
numpy                     1.20.1                   py37_0    esri
numpy-base                1.20.1                   py37_0    esri
oauthlib                  3.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h5ec785f_1
openpyxl                  3.0.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1l               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 21.0               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.2.4            py37hd77b12b_0
pandas-select             0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pandera                   0.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py37haa95532_1
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathlib2                  2.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0
pefile                    2019.4.18                  py_0
petl                      1.7.4              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow-simd               8.2.0                    py37_1    esri
pip                       21.2.2           py37haa95532_0
pluggy                    0.13.1           py37haa95532_0
postgresql                12.2                 hb652d5d_1
pro_notebook_integration  2.8                      py37_0    esri
proj                      8.0.1                h1cfcee9_0    conda-forge
proj-data                 1.6                  hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0    esri
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0    esri
psutil                    5.8.0            py37h2bbff1b_1
py                        1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyarrow                   1.0.1                         2    esri
pybind11                  2.3.0                         1    esri
pycodestyle               2.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pyflakes                  2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.7.0                      py_0    esri
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py37haa95532_0
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pypdf2                    1.26.0                     py_2    esri
pypiwin32                 223                      pypi_0    pypi
pyproj                    3.1.0            py37h9f67652_4    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py37he774522_0
pyshp                     2.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_1
pytest                    6.1.1                    py37_0    esri
python                    3.7.9                h60c2a47_0
python-certifi-win32      1.2                      py37_0    esri
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywin32                   301                      pypi_0    pypi
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32-security          228                      py37_3    esri
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py37_0    esri
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py37h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq                     19.0.2                   py37_1    esri
regex                     2021.8.3         py37h2bbff1b_0
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-kerberos         0.12.0                        0    esri
requests-negotiate-sspi   0.5.2                    py37_1    esri
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
requests-toolbelt         0.9.1                      py_0
requests_ntlm             1.1.0                      py_0    esri
rfc3986                   1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rtree                     0.9.7            py37h2eaa2aa_1
saspy                     3.6.1                      py_0    esri
scikit-learn              0.24.2           py37hf11a4ad_1
scipy                     1.6.2            py37h14eb087_0
send2trash                1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                52.0.0           py37haa95532_0
shapely                   1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
shellingham               1.4.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
simpleeval                0.9.10           py37h4ab8f01_1    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
sklearn                   0.0                      pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.2.0            py37haa95532_1
snowballstemmer           2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    4.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinx-copybutton         0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
st-dbscan                 0.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
stringcase                1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
swat                      1.8.1                    py37_0    esri
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0    esri
terminado                 0.9.4            py37haa95532_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode            1.3                        py_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyhbf3da8f_0
tiledb                    2.2.9                hf7ce2e6_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py37h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.62.2                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
typed-ast                 1.4.3            py37h2bbff1b_1
typer                     0.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.10.0.0             hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         3.10.0.0           pyh06a4308_0
typing_inspect            0.7.1              pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
ujson                     4.0.2            py37hd77b12b_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd3eb1b0_1
validators                0.18.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py37_0
win10toast                0.9                      pypi_0    pypi
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py37haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winkerberos               0.7.0                    py37_0    esri
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37he774522_1
x86cpu                    0.4                      py37_1    esri
xarray                    0.19.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
xerces-c                  3.2.3                ha925a31_0
xeus                      0.24.1                        1    esri
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xtl                       0.6.5                         1    esri
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                         0    esri
zeromq                    4.3.2                         2    esri
zipp                      3.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zope-interface            5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

I tried posting my installed packages for the environment where the code works, but hit the SE character limit. Note that `datetime` isn't installed in that environment either, and the python and `arcgis` versions are the same.

Comment: Have you tried to install datetime in the virtual environment? conda install datetime or pip install datetime

Comment: @Encomium - I could be wrong but I think datetime is built-in to python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531236/setup-py-install-requires-built-in-package-include-or-omit. pip install datetime installs a different DateTime module: https://pypi.org/project/DateTime/. I originally had that module in the error env, so I thought that was the issue -- but the error persists even after deleting it.

Comment: @ChadPeltier have the exact same issue. Any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I switched to the environment where it works without crashing, so I haven't traced the actual problem yet. I tried comparing the packages in each environment to see any differences in package versions, but nothing obvious stood out (versions of Python, arcpy, arcgis, datetime, etc.).

Comment: I eventually just deleted all conda environments from my machine and also upgraded Pro to v2.9, and I'm no longer getting this error. Unfrotunately it's unclear whether it was a problem with my conda environments or something in the verision of Pro/arcgis API for Python -- but either way, it seems to work now.